# Nokogiri on Mac: "Symbol not found: _xmlAddChild" How do I fix this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, nokogiri, bundler, libxml2

I have been running Cucumber for my Rails app for quite some time without problems.  Looks like something changed (but I don't know what), because now Nokogiri does not want to work.  Apparently it's having trouble finding the symbol "_xmlAddChild".  Not sure I even know what that means.  Can you point me in the direction of reading material that can educate me, or suggest a solution?

Here's my error output:

```
/Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby -S bundle exec cucumber  --profile default
Using the default profile...
dlopen(/Users/me/Sites/myapp/nokogiri/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle, 9): Symbol not found: _xmlAddChild
  Referenced from: /Users/me/Sites/myapp/nokogiri/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
in /Users/me/Sites/myapp/nokogiri/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle - /Users/me/Sites/myapp/nokogiri/ruby/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.bundle (LoadError)
```

Here's what I've found online:

http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=27256&group_id=494&atid=1971

I tried updating the nokogiri gem alone, and with all other gems.  No luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

Really stupid solution here.  The problem arose when another developer on the project put this line into the features/support/env.rb file used to run Cucumber.

```
require 'capybara'
```

It doesn't seem to serve a purpose, and when I removed it, the whole issue went away.  I really have no idea what the error involving "_xmlAddChild" was.